# Direction of friction for damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring, oscillators

[image]

When we study motion of springs, the force of damping(friction) is sometimes opposite to spring force (while returning to the equilibrium)  and othertimes spring force is in the direction of friction force. But when we write the equation we always take both of them to be of same sign. Why? Please explain.

Comment: ...because $v$ can have a different sign then $x$.

Comment: Doesn't the text above the equation explain? What does it say?

Comment: @Farcher 's answer is correct, but to directly address your concern, the spring force and the friction force can have opposite signs for sure. But you have to look at what each one depends on. The minus sign tells us how the spring force is opposite displacement and how friction is opposite velocity. The fact that they both have negative signs do not mean they always point in the same direction, since these forces depend on different quantities that have their own signs as well. (i.e. position and velocity can be positive and negative at different times.

Answer (score 2):

At some stage, although perhaps not formally, you have decided on a positive x-direction characterised by the unit vector $\hat i$

So the force on the mass is $-kx\, \hat i - b v\, \hat i$ where $k$ and $b$ are positive quantities.
In this expression $x$ and $v$ can be either positive and negative.

Let's see if this equation does what you expect it to do.

Suppose that $x$ is positive and the mass is moving away from the origin ($x=0$) ie $v$ is positive, then $-kx$ is negative so the force due the spring is towards the origin and $-bv$ is also negative, towards the origin which means that the frictional force is in the opposite direction (decreasing $x$) to the direction of motion of the mass  (increasing $x$).

Now suppose that $x$ is positive and the mass is moving towards the origin ie $v$ is negative.
The force due to the spring is towards the origin but $-bv$ is now positive ie away from the origin and opposite to the direction of motion.

You can also confirm that the directions of the forces are correct when $x$ is negative.